# Creating modified GROUP selection in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do probably pretty standard thing for SQL, but i had no idea how to google or search it as i can only explain what i want to achieve.

If i have one table:

```
Table X:
ID | PID | TID
1  |  1  | 2
2  |  1  | 3
3  |  2  | 3
4  |  3  | 4
5  |  4  | 1
6  |  2  | 2
```

I would like to group by `PID` (to get every `PID` only once from all over the table), but definetly get the values which are in the specified `TID` (as normal group would just select them randomly). So what i'd like my query result to be if `TID` is specified to be `'2'`:

```
Result:
ID | PID | TID
1  |  1  |  2
4  |  3  |  4 -- 4 because from all over the table and it does not have TID = 2 where PID = 3
5  |  4  |  1 -- 5 because the same as above
6  |  2  |  2 -- This is where the normal GROUP would mess up as it would give ID = 3 instead of ID = 6
```

Values with `ID`s `2` and `3` are skipped because the `PID` they have is also together with `TID = 2`

Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT pid,tid FROM tableX WHERE tid=2 GROUP BY pid UNION SELECT pid,max(tid) FROM tableX WHERE tid!=2 GROUP BY pid`.... try some variant of above query....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, grouping is the right way. The tricky part is to get the results ordered in the specified way, that is, tid=2 should be the first entry. Just ordering by tid would give tid=1 results first. The solution is to use a square function `y = (x - m)^2` with `m` being equal to the value you are seeking, thus `m = 2`.

Packing all that into a single query results in

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY (POW((tid - 2), 2))), ',', 1 ), 
  pid, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tid ORDER BY (POW((tid - 2), 2))), ',', 1 ) 
FROM so1 
GROUP BY pid 
ORDER BY AVG((POW((tid - 2), 2))) ASC
```

which yields

```
id  pid tid
1   1   2
6   2   2
5   4   1
4   3   4
```

Regarding the comment requesting to order the result by `id`, you could just wrap the query in a simple select statement:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY (POW((tid - 2), 2))), ',', 1 ) as id, 
    pid, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(tid ORDER BY (POW((tid - 2), 2))), ',', 1 ) as tid 
  FROM so1 
  GROUP BY pid 
  ORDER BY AVG((POW((tid - 2), 2))) ASC
) x 
ORDER BY x.id
```

Comment: Would there be a possibility to order them by id and still group in that way?